# Fragments, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I am doing what [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) tutorial says.
I've got a MainActivity with a navigation drawer.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package nl.broekhin.magizon;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import layout.LoginFragment;
import layout.RoosterFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




        LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        RoosterFragment roosterFragment = new RoosterFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment).commit();
    }



    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        //public void onFragmentMessage(String TAG, Object data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is my `content_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I try to launch this, I get an error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{nl.broekhin.magizon/nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity@3e4143c
>   must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: Post your MainActivity.java

Comment: @DougStevenson Done!

Comment: The problem lays in the fragment source, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

Apparently, I had to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `android.app.Fragment;`.
This is the code I got it to work with:

```
protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    t.commit();
}
```

And to set it (from the nav bar `onNavigationItemSelected()`, you do this:

```
setFragment(new RoosterFragment());
```

I hope this helps others out with the same frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a piece of code somewhere which checks if MainActivity is instance of OnFragmentInteractionListener?

If you want to communicate between Activity and Fragment, your activity needs to implement the interface Fragment defines to require.

In your case in your MainActivity after your class definition:

```
Class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

you should make it implement your OnFragmentInteractionListener interface this way:

```
Class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

After implementing the interface, you're required to implement the methods the interface defines, which you'll IDE will guide you how to do.

Comment: I don't get what this is doing. I just want the page to change when I press a button. I don't need to send info.

Comment: Can you please provide the source for your activity. If you don't want to communicate between fragment and activity, then you should just remove the check for the OnFragmentInteractionListener from your login fragment.

Comment: Done! I hope this helps

Comment: Please include the source of the fragment too, because the check for the interface requirement is there. there's code similar to this: if(getActivity() instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {...

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginFragment you are doing somewhere the following casting,

```
(OnFragmentInteractionListener)getActivity()
```

However your MainActivity doesn't implement the interface OnFragmentInteractionListener (even though you have defined it). The solution is simple. Change,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your login fragment?

I guess the problem is that you're inflating the wrong layout file in your activity. Please check the inflated file. In your activity it says R.layout.activity_main but you named your xml as content_main.xml

Comment: It's just a blank fragment. I haven't edited it at all.

Comment: Updated my question, check that out and give me some feedback

Comment: is the content_main.xml file your main activity's layout file?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to implement OnFragmentIntractionListner interface in your activity..

Comment: I have tried running it again with `public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
}` But it is not working